# Iterating through generator in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

this code

```
let func = function *(){
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        yield i;
    }
}
let s = func().next();
console.log(s);
let s2 = func().next();
console.log(s2);
```

returns

```
Object {value: 1, done: false}
Object {value: 1, done: false}
```

so basically func yields first value all the time.

But when I change to

```
let f = func();
let s = f.next();
console.log(s);
let s2 = f.next();
console.log(s2);
```

it works as expected.
Why assigning func to variable makes such a difference?

Comment: Because `func() !== func()`?

Comment: If it would behave differently, then every generator function could only be used *once*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first bit of code, you are always creating a new generator instance. I've assigned those instances to separate variables to illustrate this more clearly:

```
// first generator instance
let g = func();
// first call to next on the first instance
let s = g.next();
console.log(s);
// second generator instance
let g2 = func();
// first call to next on the second instance
let s2 = g2.next();
console.log(s2);
```

Whereas in your second snippet, you keep iterating the same generator (assigned to the variable `f`):

```
let f = func();
// first call to next
let s = f.next();
console.log(s);
// second call to next
let s2 = f.next();
console.log(s2);
```